# Is there a steam-like service for purchasing DC comic books online?

Tags: dc

I live in South America and would love to purchase The New 52 series of my favoritie characters. My son and I would love to read them as bed time stories.

There are no comic book stores down here and my options are limited to piracy.

I would much rather have the convenience of purchasing the digital comic book legally and having it available on my machine easily.

Does DC offer a digital purchase of comic books service?

Comment: This is pretty easily solved with a google search, or simply going to www.dccomics.com

Comment: That was the first place I looked and I could only find `Purchase Print` as purchase options.

Comment: If you click on the "Comics" tab there is a tab on the right that says "Buy Now" and the first option is "Digital Comics"

Comment: Both DC and Marvel release digital versions of their new comics the same day as print.

Comment: @Monty129: To be fair, a lot of people's first instinct would be to click on the "shop" tab, which takes you to the DC store, where they only have print comics. Also, the DC digital comics format is a bit rubbish. It's online-only, and you need to log into the site via a browser or the iOS/Android app to read them. Not a great purchasing option...

Comment: "There are no comic book stores down here and my options are limited to piracy." - Um, how  about mail oder?

Comment: @Michael: That's a bit costly when you consider how much shipping is (especially with the USPS hikes after the pension funding BS). It usually isn't worthwhile to mail order items that are less than $20 regularly, even more so with international rates. That's if he even lives in a country that American businesses will sell/ship to. E.g. a lot of businesses won't ship to Italy, and many businesses won't accept credit cards from Nigeria, the Philippines, Argentina, amongst other places.

Comment: @Lèse majesté: there probably are comic shops in Serg's country's largest cities (if not: business concept!), and they may do mail orders. As for shipping costs, I'd say that most people could live with accumulated monthly rather than weekly delivery.

Comment: @Michael: Ah, I thought you meant ordering from US distributors. If he can find a domestic mail-order service and place his orders monthly, that would definitely make it much more practical.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like an ad to me...

Comment: @Lèsemajesté DC and Marvel don't sell DRM-free downloads of their comics.  [Some other](http://thrillbent.com/blog/at-long-last-storefront/) online comic sellers do offer that feature, but you won't see this for the big 2.

Comment: @WOPR In what way does this look like an ad?

Comment: @Keen: that's predictable since, like ebooks, they haven't undergone the same sort of forced transformation that the music and film industries have. But at the very least they should have provided a downloadable PDF or epub format, both of which have DRM capabilities but can still be read offline on one's platform of choice (the Comixology app does let you download and read offline within the app, but it's only available for iOS, Android, Kindle Fire, and Windows 8; Linux, OS X, Windows 7 and other users are out of luck).

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Amazon (and maybe B&N's Nook) have DRM downloads.  I don't recommend them because of how much better the Comixology's UX is.

Comment: @Keen: Still no Linux reader for KF8 but if they're available in ePub format from B&N, that would be great. What UX differences do you prefer in Comixology? Is it the way it groups comics into series or the reading experience? I can't see any advantages in the web-based reader over Kindle for PC.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté On my Ipad, the Amazon reader is clearly not designed for comic books.  I vaguely recall it lacking 2 page view, a way to zoom in to panels, etc.  Comic-book centric features weren't there because their app is aimed at normal book reading.  I can't speak to the web apps, since I just use the tablet app or the Windows 8 app.

Answer (score 9):

There is [Comixology](http://www.comixology.com/), a digital distribution platform. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ComiXology), they offer more than 30,000 titles for a variety of platforms (iOS, Android, Windows 8, Kindle)

Edit: Just to be clear, through Comixology you can purchase titles from DC, Marvel, Image, etc. I think they list 101 different [publishers](http://www.comixology.com/browse-publisher).

Comment: This is apparently the platform that DC Comics uses when you purchase digital comics on their site.

Comment: Yup. E.g. Comixology have their own app on the iOS App Store. DC have an app too, but it's just a branded version of Comixology, with its catalogue limited to DC titles.